# How to show association's name in rails admin ? (instead of id)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have an `Editor` model with `has_many :categories`, and `has_many :types`, through the tables `categories_editors` and `editors_types`.

In the admin interface I would like to see the name of the `categories`. It is working for `types` (see the image below), however both associations are defined the same way.

[image]

```
class Editor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categories_editors
  has_many :categories, through: :categories_editors
  has_many :editors_types
  has_many :types, through: :editors_types
end

class Type < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :editors_types
  has_many :editors, through: :editors_types
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categories_editors
  has_many :editors, through: :categories_editors
end

class CategoriesEditor < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :editor
  belongs_to :category
end

class EditorsType < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :editor
  belongs_to :type
end
```

Does someone has an idea ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To have the name of your object displaying you have to rename your column `name`

So I changed :

```
  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "category"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

to :

```
  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Comment: It's a way of doing it but not a must. You can also set object_label_method to the field you want to show. Also you can concat more than one field value or add some formatting under this method in your model.